# Lytebox Very Slow in FF9 but fine in IE9

Tags: lightbox, lytebox

Does anyone know why Lytebox is so slow in FF9?  I so is there a solution?  It works well in IE9 and Safari.  I've read other posts which seem to say it's the other way around so I'm puzzled.  I've tried using Lightbox but found it doesn't work well on my site.

Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let people know.  I've had to replace lyebox with Colorbox which is much faster and seemingly has less problems conflicting with other scripts (Lightbox, Fancybox and others wouldn't work for me).